# Linux command to download a file from internet in concole

Tags: centos

I'm trying to install "Meld" in CentOS 7, but I'm new to Linux don't know how to install Meld. In internet i found the following steps

```
1. Download latest epel-release rpm from
http://download-ib01.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/
2. Install epel-release rpm:
# rpm -Uvh epel-release*rpm
3. Install meld rpm package:
# yum install meld
```

but don't know how to download the file in console. So if you could help me with exact command to download the file it would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You do the following to download:

```
wget https://download-ib01.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/e/epel-release-7-12.noarch.rpm
wget https://download-ib01.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/e/epel-rpm-macros-7-23.noarch.rpm
```

Comment: You don’t even need to use wget. Just yum install URL.